# Tangent plane to the hyperboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-spaces

> **Problem:** How can I show that the tangent plane to the hyperboloid  $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$ at point $(2,2,3)$ has equation $2(x-2)+2(y-2)-3(z-3)=0$

Attempt: Is the idea here is to slice the hyperboloid say at $x=2$ and $y=2$ to find to vectors say $v$ and $w$ and then taking there crossproduct gives the desired equation. But i'm getting nowhere. Is my approach correct? Any idea and hints would be much much appreciated!

Comment: $$\nabla f|_{P_0}\cdot(P-P_0)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the hyperboloid of equation (you should have defined the precise equation in your question)
$$\Gamma\equiv x^2+y^2-z^2=-1.$$
Obviously $(2,2,3)\in\Gamma$. A plane in $\mathbb R^3$ is defined by a point and a orthogonal vector.
Since you want the plane tangent to the surface of the hyperboloid we'll take as orthogonal vector the gradient of the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}$ evaluated in $(2,2,3)$, which is given by
$$\nabla f(x,y)\vert_{(2,2)}=\Bigg(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}},\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}\Bigg)\Bigg\vert_{(2,2)}=\bigg(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\bigg)$$
so the plane will have equation
$$z-f(2,3)=\Big\langle\big(x-2,y-2\big),\big((\nabla f\vert_{(2,2)})_x,(\nabla f\vert_{(2,2)})_y\big) \Big\rangle$$
$$\pi\equiv \frac{2}{3}(x-2)+\frac{2}{3}(y-2)-(z-3)=0$$
$$\fbox{$2(x-2)+2(y-2)-3(z-3)=0$}$$

Comment: Why don't you just take the 3D gradient, that's simpler ?